# Detail about SXA Dynamic Placeholders Rendering and it's datasource not in Layout Service API Json Result

Tags: sxa-jss

- `Sitecore Version- 10.3.0 (rev. 008463)`
- `Sitecore SXA and Headless using with nextjs`

We are using `Sitecore 10.3.0 SXA headless with nextjs`. and Configured a partial design for articlepage. We setup a "ArticleContent" rendering that have configured with dynamic placeholder "article" as below image.
[image]

We created an "Article Page using this Partial Design". and Setup ArticleHero component, that is allowed for "article" placeholder. We can see on layout detail popup dynamic placeholder key comes as expected, and it also render content on page as expected. but layout service api is not returning any data in json, about the renderings those are place on dynamic placeholder.

[image]

We can see on page it renders data as expected.

[image]

So here my concern is this, Does this expected behavior from layout service api data with dynamic placeholder rendering. I was expecting all detail about these rendering and about its datasource should be in json result.

Note: For these rendering IsRenderingsWithDynamicPlaceholders is applied true. As it reference from sitecore docs. And If we use static placeholder then can see these rendering and its datasource detail in layout service json data.

Comment: Layout Service works only with placeholder settings created globally. All directly added placeholder settings to the presentation of the items are ignored. Add your placeholder to the Layout Service Placeholders field in your rendering item or your layout.